# where to create ansible hosts file in virtualenv?

Tags: pip, ansible, virtualenv

I installed ansible with pip into my virtualenv, but I didn't find hosts file.

I have one `/etc/ansible/hosts`, but this is related to global install of ansible on the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create inventory file anywhere you like.

Just point Ansible to it via `-i /path/to/inventory` parameter or setting:

```
[defaults]
inventory = /path/to/inventory
```

in your local `ansible.cfg` file.

Ansible searches for config file here (in this order):

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Comment: where is ansible.cfg file?

Comment: It can be at many locations, for example in your current working directory. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in virtualenv you specify the directory in which you host files. try to create the related directory structure in it. 
~/ansible.cfg overrides the systemwide ansible configs, so you can specify the inventory file in ansible.cfg in the virtualenv's directory path.